# How to validate a JWS in an older framework?

Tags: .net, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, openid

We have an older CMS (Kentico 11), which is ASP.NET-based (not Core, not Blazor, not MVC). For various reasons we can't just replace it any time soon. As part of the process of replacing our web offerings gradually we would like to build in a piece that will authenticate against our Azure AD B2C tenant so the old CMS content and the new pieces we roll out can be using the same authentication authority.

Obviously this older code base does not include any support for more recent Microsoft Identity interactions. We are unable to use any of the **Microsoft.Identity** libraries since that whole project is built for .NET Core. We *can* successfully hand off the authentication to the B2C workflow and get back an Open ID token, and we can read the claims in the token. We have also succeeded in reading the public key exponent and modulus for validating the token signature from the **b2clogin.com** site. What we don't know how to do is actually validate the signature. Pretty much every article we've found says, at this point in the process, "validate the signature using your favorite library".

We don't know how to find a library that might help us at this level. All of the Microsoft libraries for this purpose, as noted above, require .NET Core or a newer version of .NET Framework. We did happen across the Bouncy Castle project (https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html), but the C# version of their API has apparently no documentation so we're not sure how we might take advantage of  it.

So, basically: We have the B2C public key, and we have the token signature which, if I understand what I've read, is a private-key encrypted digest of the rest of the token. What do we actually do with these? Is it a matter of decrypting the signature and matching the digest, or is there more to it? Or better, is there a Framework 4.6.1-compatible library that knows how to do this and has documentation that will make sense to JWT and cryptographic novices?

Comment: There is a collection of libraries here - one of them may suit? - https://jwt.io/libraries

Comment: Or this? - https://developer.okta.com/code/dotnet/jwt-validation/

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be very simple, once you have the right information. Having translated the signature, the rest of the token minus the signature, and the public key modulus and exponent, into byte arrays, this is all there is to it:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters { Exponent = exponent, Modulus = modulus });

bool isSignatureVerified = rsa.VerifyData(tokenMinusSignature, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(hashAlgorithmFromTokenHeader), signature);
```

Our understanding, described above, of how to verify was nearly correct. The important missing piece was the difference between encryption and signing, explained with admirable clarity here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php